# How to put row into one JTable using the data inside of the two database

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable, tablemodel

guys? help me with my problem. I want to have a one jtable that populates data using two table from database. i have two methods inside my class Apple..

Class Apple;

```
public void table(){

    try{

        String id = num.getText();

        rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM payments;");

        Vector<String> header = new Vector<String>();

                    header.add("PAYMENT"); 
        header.add("AMOUNT");
        header.add("MODIFIER");
        header.add("DATE MODIFIED");

        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new  Vector<Vector<Object>>();

        while(rs.next()) {

            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();

    row.add(rs.getString("description"));
    row.add(rs.getString("amount")); 
    row.add(rs.getString("remarks")); 
    row.add(rs.getString("date"));

            data.add(row);

        } // loop

        dtm.setDataVector(data , header);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        scrollPane.setBounds(0,0,490,250);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        validate();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error in table: "+e);
    }//try and catch

}//tble
```

that's the first method inside class Apple, and `rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM payments;");` is the first database table i want to retrieve the data and insert inside my jtable.. after it insert inside my jtable i have another method that will retrieve data from another database table..

```
public void table(){

    try{

        String id = num.getText();

        rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM record where idNum ='"+id+"';");

        while(rs.next()){

            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();

            row.add(rs.getString("description"));
            row.add(rs.getString("amount")); 
            row.add(rs.getString("remarks")); 
            row.add(rs.getString("date"));

            data.add(row);

        } // while

        dtm.setDataVector(data , header);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        scrollPane.setBounds(0,0,490,250);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        validate();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error in table: "+e);
    }//try and catch

}//tble
```

this is the second methd inside the class apple.. i want its data to be added into my jtable and not deleting the previous data inserted inside the jtable..sorry for my poor english grammar..hope you understand what i mean..

Comment: 1a. don't to create any GUI Object inside try - catch (- I miss there finally with ResultSet.close() etc), because  on 1st exception everything gone away, 1b. prepare those Object before, 1c. better as local variable, 2. don't to use NullLayout, 3a. question in this form, with this description and code snipped isn't answerable here, 3b. for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilalbe, 3c. with hardcoded value in loca variable for JTable (its XxxTableModel) instead of JDBC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do join operation in single query between `payments` and `record` table and retrieve result on `JTable`.

Comment: how to joim operation in single query?